# Is there an 'OrElse' equivalent in javascript?

Tags: javascript

If i have this line in vb.net

```
If (a = Nothing OrElse a.value = Nothing) Then 
    DoSomething()
End If
```

It is the equivalent of

```
if (a = nothing) Then 
    DoSomething()
else
    if (a.value = nothing) Then
        DoSomething()
    End If
End If
```

So essentially what makes 'OrElse' different from 'Or' is that the right hand side is only evaluated if the left hand side should return false, in this case that is necessary because if I were to check for a.value while a is othing then I'd get a null reference exception.

Is there an equivalent to OrElse operator in javascript?

Comment: Is it acceptable for you to use else if (a.value = nothing) ??

Comment: How is this different from JavaScript's or-operator `||`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

this works.  ( it's called short circuiting )

```
if(!a || !a.value) { 
  doSomething()
}
```

Comment: careful, that would be true if a.value is the number 0 (string '0' is fine though)

Comment: yes.... all the usual warnings about using ! for checking for null / undefined ness applies :)

Answer (score 3):

In JavaScript the `||` operator is short-circuiting, but `|` (which doubles as a bitwise OR operator) is not short-circuiting.

It's the same in all C-syntax languages, including C# and Java, though given `a||b` not all languages guarantee that `a` will be evaluated before `b` (they might choose to evaluate `b` first). Always check your language specification.